# nancy - what else must I do to get the spark recognised in testing

Tags: nancy

I have looked at the relevant documentation. I have added Simple.Data, and Simple.Data.Spark into a Classlibrary for testing, but I get the following message -- What extra must I do so that the Spark views I have pasted into the  Classlibrary project to get the classlibrary to find it? This is the error message it says it only recognises the these extensions: sshtml,html,htm

Unable to locate view 'AddressList'
Currently available view engine extensions: sshtml,html,htm
Locations inspected: AddressList,views/AddressList,views//AddressList,/AddressList,views/Address/AddressList,Address/AddressList

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things. First you need to reference the view engine from the test project, this is due to the fact on how assembly loading works in .net (a reference's sibling references aren't automatically loaded into the application domain unless explicitly used).

The second is the view itself. Because all test runners copy the assembly, that is under test, to an isolated location and because views are contents files.. the views them selves aren't copied to the isolated location automatically. The easiest way to get around this is to set the view files so they're always copied to the output location (using the VS properties window)

Let me know if it works out for you

Comment: Thanks @TheCodeJunkie for the help. (Sorry for the delay getting back to you.) I made several changes and not sure which one it was that actually got me up & running. One of the issues was the version-ing used with Sqlite -- which I ended ripping out. Thanks all the same...

Comment: Happy to do that --- not sure how though.. Don't I need more accrued points for that?

Comment: You click the up arrow next to my answer and click to accept it as the correct one

Comment: Thanks. Says I need 15 reputation to do it. I have 0. So soz.

Comment: Maybe you'll also find [this link](http://www.jefclaes.be/2012/06/making-my-first-nancyfx-test-pass.html) useful.